# Platform Events for child is getting published before parent

Tags: apex, event, platform-event, streaming-api, publish-subscribe

I am publishing the events in order such that Parent event is published first then the child. Using System.debug I can see that the controller goes to publish event method for Parent and then the child . But the ReplayId of child is less than the parent indicating that child event was published first.

Is there any particular reason for this ?

Comment: It depends on how you publish. Please edit your post and include enough code for MVR (minimum viable reproduction).

Answer (score 0):

Replay Ids increment per Platform Event SObject type

So, if you publish events for `Foo__e` and `Bar__e` across the org, each object starts with ReplayId of 0 and increments based on how many events of that object type published org lifetime-to-date

Looking at my org where I have a dozen xxx__e SObjectTypes, I see many share the same replayId